# React native web scraping submit form

Tags: react-native

I`m trying to set up a little React Native App. The app should have a login screen, after a successful login you go to the next screen where a pdf gets displayed. 
The pdf is from a website. So I have to log in on the website (with the data from the login screen) and fill in that form, submit it and finally, I can reach that pdf I want.

Is there a way, like a library or a framework/tool or whatever to achieve that form submit?

Comment: To let users login to your app you could use Firebase Authentication or write it from scratch with ExpressJS and some database

Comment: but how can i pass the data from my login screen (in the app) to the website and perform the login there?